# How can I use java Integer.parseInt()?

Tags: java

I was trying to change like  String A00001 to int 1 in this code, but Eclipse told me that

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
>  For input string: `"00001                        "`
>   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown
>   Source) 
>  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) 
>  at
>   LibraryManager.BookAdd.getInsertOrderedList(BookAdd.java:105)

Here is my code :

```
while(rs1.next()){
    allid[i]=rs1.getString("id");
    String mystr=allid[i].substring(1);
    try{
        System.out.println(mystr);//this print 00001
        intofid[i]=Integer.parseInt(mystr);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    i++;
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

You have blanks at the end of your string `"00001                        "`. That's why the string can not be parsed as an integer. you can `trim` the string and the exception will gone:

```
intofid[i]=Integer.parseInt(mystr.trim());
```

Comment: that's true, I was defined the 'id' as char() type not varchar() in table,finally got it,thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hiro , there is a trailing space in your string. You will need to trim it.

```
String str = "0001 ";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str.trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach in case of trailing and leading spaces, even spaces inside numbers. For example:

```
String mystr = "  00 0001   ";
intofid[i] = Integer.parseInt(mystr.replace(" ",""));
```

Comment: better than wich approach? trim() delete both leading and trailing blanks